# Restoring a control's position and size inside the form at runtime. (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a DataGridView in one of my form which at a certain point I resize an change it's position. I would like to be able to restore it to the designer's default position at runtime. I know I could save it before changing and then restoring it later, but I feel like there surely is a way in .NET to just restore a control position to it's default. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way is to store the coordinates and the size of the control, then to reapply them to it.

Before moving:

```
private Point _location;
private Size _size;

private void EventFired(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _location = myControl.Location;
    _size = myControl.Size;

    // Move control
}
```

After moving:

```
myControl.Location = _location;
myControl.Size = _size;
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about the point structure which makes it pretty easy

Answer (score 1):

There is no such concept as 'default control position'.  All controls are positioned from code that is created in `InitControls()`.  To restore 'default position', capture `Location` rectangle in `OnLoad()` and restore to that value when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for necro-posting, but you could use the tag property of your control (if not already in use)

**To Store:**

```
myControl.Tag = myControl.Bounds
```

or

```
myControl.GetType().GetProperty("Tag").SetValue(myControl, myControl.GetType().GetProperty("Bounds").GetValue(myControl, Nothing), Nothing)
```

**To restore:**

```
myControl.Bounds = myControl.Tag
```

or

```
myControl.GetType().GetProperty("Bounds").SetValue(myControl, myControl.GetType().GetProperty("Tag").GetValue(myControl, Nothing), Nothing)
```